# Azure uploadfromfileasync throws timeout exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

blockBlob.uploadFromFileAsync()=> throws the client could not finish the operation within specified timeout when the file is larger in say(>2 GB).
I am uploading a zip file.

```
BlobRequestOptions blobrequestoption= new BlobRequestOptions 
{ 
    ParallelOperationThreadCount=64,
    DisableContentMD5Validation=true, 
    storeBlobUploadContentMD5=false, 
    singleBlobUploadThreshholdInBytes=100*1024*1024 
}; 
CancellationToken cancellationtoken=new CancellationToken();
IProgress<storageProgress> progresshandler=new Progress<StorageProgress>(
   progress=> logger.consoleDebug(((progress.BytesTranserred)/(1024*1024)) +"transferred")
var _task=Task.run(()=> blockBlob.uploadFromFileAsync(sourceFilePAth, null, blobrequestoption,null,progressHandler,cancellationtoken)); 
_task.wait();
```

Comment: Please share what request options have you set in `blobrequestoption`? Please do not provide this information in comments. Instead edit your question and include all the details there only.

Comment: Hi again, thanks, but a little more context would be nice. There are a lot of experienced developers out here who are able, even without having experience with the technology you are using, to pinpoint the exact problem in no time. The only thing they need is that you provide details on the types you're using and the values of the parameters you're putting in there.

Comment: Hi @Dineshsekar, please [edit]  you question to add the code.

Comment: You can try by reducing the value of `ParallelOperationThreadCount` from 64 to say 4. Maximum value should not be more than the number of logical processors on the computer from where you're running the code.

Comment: Also try to change `singleBlobUploadThreshholdInBytes` value from 100MB to say 4MB.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri , it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @GauravMantri pointed out, to fix the `time out` issue, you should reduce the value of `ParallelOperationThreadCount` from 64 to a proper number. Maximum value should not be more than the number of logical processors on your computer.

And the `singleBlobUploadThreshholdInBytes` value setting as 100MB might cause the `time out` issue in some cases, like in a bad network situation. You can set it to a smaller one like 4MB.

Comment: reducing the ParallelOperationThreadCount solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The singleBlobUploadThreshholdInBytes can be omitted because based on documentation -> "This value will be ignored if the ParallelOperationThreadCount is set to a value greater than 1"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.singleblobuploadthresholdinbytes?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes