# Upload to blob storage from xamarin application

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I have a mobile application built in Xamarin. I have a gunctionality to record video and then I need to upload it to Blob Storage. The video size may be 100 MB or 200 MB. Below is the code

```
BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient("storageConnectionString");
BlobContainerClient containerClient = client.GetBlobContainerClient("ContainerName");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream("Array of bytes");
await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync("fileName", memoryStream);
memoryStream.Close();
memoryStream.Dispose();
```

I have the below exception when trying to upload large videos for example 60 MB video

```
Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) 
(The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) 
(The operation was canceled.)


at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, 
System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline, System.Boolean async) [0x001b8] in     
<bc1a25630f42495eb986d0b74fe4ff40>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message,         
System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) [0x00086] in <bc1a25630f42495eb986d0b74fe4ff40>:0 
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, 
System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) [0x00086] in <bc1a25630f42495eb986d0b74fe4ff40>:0 
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync (Azure.Core.HttpMessage message, 
System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] pipeline) [0x00086] in <bc1a25630f42495eb986d0b74fe4ff40>:0 
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient+BlockBlob.UploadAsync (Azure.Core.Pipeline.ClientDiagnostics 
clientDiagnostics, Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline pipeline, System.Uri resourceUri, 
System.IO.Stream body, System.Int64 contentLength, System.String version, System.Nullable`1[T] 
timeout, System.Byte[] transactionalContentHash, System.String blobContentType, System.String 
blobContentEncoding, System.String blobContentLanguage, System.Byte[] blobContentHash, System.String 
blobCacheControl, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] metadata, System.String 
leaseId, System.String blobContentDisposition, System.String encryptionKey, System.String 
encryptionKeySha256, System.Nullable`1[T] encryptionAlgorithm, System.String encryptionScope, 
System.Nullable`1[T] tier, System.Nullable`1[T] ifModifiedSince, System.Nullable`1[T] 
ifUnmodifiedSince, System.Nullable`1[T] ifMatch, System.Nullable`1[T] ifNoneMatch, System.String 
ifTags, System.String requestId, System.String blobTagsString, System.Boolean async, System.String 
operationName, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001e2] in 
<306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in 
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020- 
02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.UploadInternal (System.IO.Stream content, 
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders, 
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] metadata, 
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tags, 
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions conditions, System.Nullable`1[T] accessTier, 
System.IProgress`1[T] progressHandler, System.String operationName, System.Boolean async, 
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00334] in 
<306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0 
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient+<>c_DisplayClass54_0. 
<GetPartitionedUploaderBehaviors>b_0 (System.IO.Stream stream, 
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobUploadOptions args, System.IProgress`1[T] progressHandler, 
System.String operationName, System.Boolean async, System.Threading.CancellationToken 
cancellationToken) [0x000c9] in <306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0 
at Azure.Storage.PartitionedUploader`2[TServiceSpecificArgs,TCompleteUploadReturn].UploadInternal 
(System.IO.Stream content, TServiceSpecificArgs args, System.IProgress`1[T] progressHandler, 
System.Boolean async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ce] in 
<306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0 
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.StagedUploadInternal (System.IO.Stream content, 
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobUploadOptions options, System.Boolean async, 
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001c5] in 
<306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0 
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync (System.String blobName, System.IO.Stream 
content, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00083] in 
<306eef6cb8644c19b928e83686007d43>:0
```

Comment: How big is the data you're trying to upload?

Comment: I need to save about 2 minutes videos. Now i am trying on a file with size 53 MB

Comment: Please see my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691236/azure-uploadfromfileasync-throws-timeout-exception.